# generate-id() too slow for large document

Tags: xslt

I have a large xml document containing annotated speech transcripts. Following is a short fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<U>
    <A/>
    <C type="start" id="cb01s"/>
    <P/>
    <T>a</T>
    <T>woman</T>
    <P/>
    <T>took</T>
    <T>off</T>
    <T>the</T>
    <T>train</T>
    <C type="end" id="cb02e"/>
    <P/>
    <T>but</T>
    <P/>
    <F/>
    <RT>
        <O>
            <C type="start" id="cb03s"/>
            <T>her</T>
            <T>bag</T>
            <P/>
            <T>are</T>
        </O>
        <P/>
        <E>
            <C type="start" id="cb04s"/>
            <T>her</T>
            <T>bag</T>
            <T>are</T>
        </E>
    </RT>
    <P/>
    <T>still</T>
    <P/>
    <T>in</T>
    <T>the</T>
    <T>train</T>
    <C type="end" id="cb05e"/>
    <PC>.</PC>
</U>
```

The basic task I need to do is to get the number of `<T>` nodes between certain pairs of `<C>` nodes. I've used the following stylesheet fragment to do this (illustrating with one specific pair of `<C>` nodes).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="U">
        <xsl:variable name="start-node" select="descendant::C[@id = 'cb01s']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="end-node" select="descendant::C[@id = 'cb02e']"/>
        <xsl:text>Result: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($start-node/following::T[following::C[generate-id(.) = generate-id($end-node)]])"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works fine on such a short XML fragment as above and gives the correct result: `Result: 6`.

However, the actual XML document contains tens of thousands of `<C>` nodes and even more `<T>` nodes. So when I try to run the stylesheet on it the result comes back *very* slowly. (It would probably take days to finish completely.) I suppose the problem must be that on each run of the `<xsl:value-of...` line, the processor (Saxon) is checking all `<T>` nodes and generating id's for `<C>` nodes multiples times (i.e., exponentially) and that slows everything down.

Is there a way to speed up the process while still using generate-id()? Or do I need to get the number of `<T>` nodes with some alternate approach?

Comment: Do all `<T>` for any single range belong to the same `<U>`?

Comment: Yes. That would be the most minimal encapsulating node. In most cases, a `<U>` node might consist of a few dozen `<T>` nodes.

Comment: Is that Saxon 9 or 6 or why do you think you need generate-id at all and that it is the culprit of the performance problem. If you use Saxon 9 the profile the code (see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/performanceanalysis/) where the problem comes from. And of course the check `following::C[generate-id(.) = generate-id($end-node)]` in XSLT 2 can be written as `following::C[1] is $end-node`. XSLT 2.0 also has the `<<` and `>>` operators and `for-each-group group-starting/ending-with` for other approaches.

Comment: I'm using Saxon 9.4. I think I need to use generate-id() because there may be intervening `<C>` nodes that must be ignored. (Sorry that's not exemplified in the sample XML fragment above.) So, `following::C[1]` would not necessarily identify `$end-node`.  I'm also currently stuck with XSLT 1.0.  I'll try using the performance analysis feature. I've done it somewhat already using simple `xsl:message` outputs, and that leads me to conclude that the slowdown is with the `<xsl:value-of...` line.

Comment: Saxon 9.4 is an XSLT 2.0 processor so if you use it I don't see why you are stuck with XSLT 1.0. Even if you have `version="1.0"` in your stylesheets yo can use all XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 features with Saxon 9.4.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am currently using Saxon 9.4 to code my stylesheet, but I have to be able to use it in other environments that are limited to XSLT 1.0.  I should have made that clear at the outset.

Comment: I still don't see the point of `generate-id()`.  Intervening `<C>` nodes are not an issue when you are anyway looking for one with a specified `id` attribute (as opposed to a generated ID), which indeed is what you seem to be describing.

Comment: Following @Tomalak's comment above, I realized that things might speed up if I could constrain the node-set that generate-id works on. So, I've modified the `<xsl:value-of...` search path so that it only evaluates `<T>` and `<C>` nodes *within* the current `<U>` nodes. I added id's to all the `<U>` nodes and then use the following to get the result (where $u-id is the relevant id): `<xsl:value-of select="count($start-node/following::T[ancestor::U[@id = $u-id]][following::C[ancestor::U[@id = $u-id]][generate-id(.) = generate-id($end-node)]])`. This speeds things up enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, @JohnBollinger and @MartinHonnen. I understand now. For this problem, I can simplify what I wrote in my last comment as: `<xsl:value-of select="count($start-node/following::T[ancestor::U[@id = $u-id]][following::C[ancestor::U[@id = $u-id]][@id = $end-node-id]])`, where `$end-node-id` is the relevant `<C>` node's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `generate-id()` just to avoid matching `<C>` elements intervening between the start and end nodes.  You are matching `<C>` elements by their `id` attributes in the first place, and I see no reason not to use that more directly.  For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="U">
        <xsl:variable name="start-id" select="cb01s"/>
        <xsl:variable name="end-id" select="cb02e"/>

        <xsl:text>Result: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::C[@id = $start-id]/following::T[following::C[@id = $end-id][1]])"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can simplify that by removing the `[1]` position predicate if you can rely on the `<C>` element `@id`s to be unique in the document.

If `generate-id()` is indeed the primary cause of your performance problem, then avoiding it altogether ought to provide a big boost.